# Power Automate - Changing a column's properties removes it from the schema

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Before I go tear apart an entire workflow and app to fix this, I wanted to see if there was a simpler solution.

I have a flow in SPO that needs to set a People column with an "Update Item" action. Originally that column was set to allow multiple people, and that was fine. Then I ran into an issue where I had to switch it to single selections instead. That broke the workflow, naturally. At first it was giving me an error saying the field didn't exist anymore and should be removed from the schema of the update. I just deleted and re-added the "Update Item" action, but now the People column isn't even showing up.

My only idea is to completely rip out and recreate the column, but that would bust various parts of the workflow and its associated app. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems to be a refreshing issue. Maybe in the **Update action** select a different list and see if that list's columns show up. And then select your list. Another option to log out, close the browser and log back in. Also, you can try to add a dummy column to your list and see if that column show up in the Update Action.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but the same results are showing up. The column is still bugged

Comment: Create a brand new manually trigger Flow and use a **Get items** and a **Compose** to see if you get values for the people column for this list

Comment: Everything shows up fine in the new flow, it's the existing one that has the problem. Is there a way to maybe redo/refresh the connection to SPO?

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the type of data needs to be consistent, otherwise some errors will indeed occur.

Per my understanding,similar issues may be due to that Power Automate keeps a reference of the "old" column, but since it's not present anymore and has an object associated with it, it keeps it but warns that that column doesn't exist anymore.

And this question is more related to PowerAutomate you could also post a thread in the [Power Automate Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Power-Automate/ct-p/FL_GeneralDiscussions) to seek for Professional advice.

Reference:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/SubmissionTime-no-longer-present/td-p/637415